# Brownian motion joint probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\{W_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion, and for each $t>0$ define $M_t=\max_{0\leq s \leq t} W_s$. Find the joint probability density of the random variables $(W_t, M_t)$.

Could anyone please help on how to proceed with this, I have solved his by assuming the two events are independent but i do't think that is the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the reflection principle, the joint CDF of $(M_t, W_t)$ is
$$
F_{t}(a,x)=\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{2a-x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)-1, \quad a>0, a\ge x.
$$

Differentiation $F_t$ w.r.t. $a$ and $x$ one gets
$$
f_t(a,x)=\frac{2(2a-x)}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}e^{-\frac{(2a-x)^2}{2t}}.
$$

Comment: Can you proceed by finding a formula for P{Mt>x and Wt<x−y} for x,y>0.

Comment: It's
$$
1-\Phi\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{t}}\right).
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? The CDF in the answer and comment are different, just to confirm both are correct?

Comment: $F_t(a,x)=\mathsf{P}(M_t\le a, W_t\le x)$. In the comment you asked about $\mathsf{P}(M_t > x, W_t < x-y)$. Also notice that
$$
\mathsf{P}(W_t\le x)=\mathsf{P}(M_t\le a,W_t\le x)+\mathsf{P}(M_t>a,W_t\le x).
$$